# send data to php JSON way from html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to send POST data using JavaScript. I have data in HTML form :

```
<form name="messageact" action="">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="username" size="15" />
    <input name="massage" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
</form>
```

after press submit key i want to send name and massage to my PHP file ! a wrote this for my JavaScript in html : post.php , with post method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //If user submits the form
    $("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
        return false;
    });
```

and for my php i wrote this :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    ....
    ....
```

but in PHP i couldn't receive anything ! please help me to solve this problem ! and how can i change it to JSON way ?

Comment: java is not javascript

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to store name in the $_SESSION?
If you have used $_SESSION by mistake change this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];
....
....
```

to this and it should work

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    ....
    ....
```

The $_POST and $_SESSION are 2 different variables. You might wanna take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for send data to server just submit the form and add the destination php in action

```
 <form name="messageact" action="post.php">
   <input name="name" type="text" id="username" size="15" />
   <input name="massage" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
   <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
 </form>
```

for testing **post.php** you could use this code

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
   echo  $_POST['name'] . <br />;
   echo  $_POST['massage'] . <br />;
   echo  $_POST['submitmsg'] . <br />;
?>
```

if you want ajax behavior  try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //If user submits the form
    $("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
       var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
       $.post("post.php", {submitmsg: clientmsg});              
       $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
 return false;
});
```

Comment: What if he doesn't want the page to be refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form name="messageact" method="post" action="post.php">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="username" size="15" />
    <input name="message" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
</form>

$("#submitmsg").click(function(e){
    var name = $("#username").val();
    var usermsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.post("post.php", {'name': name,'usermsg':usermsg});
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i do it for java :

```
    //If user submits the form
    $('#edit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'post.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data:$('#edit').serialize(),
        success:function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            $('#feedback').html(data).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        },
        error: function( jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ){
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

and for form :

```
<form id="edit" action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" >
<input type="text" name="phone" >
<input type="text" name="address" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```